# R: Can I run source()’d code without altering the main environment?

Tags: r, include, environment, child-process

In R, I want to `source()` code that was written for other purposes, to grab some objects it creates. But I don’t want that sourced code to overwrite objects in my main program, and I don’t want sourced code to load libraries that may mask functions I use in my main program (like how loading plyr after dplyr will mask some dplyr functions).

In plain code (no `source()`’d code), I can run some code in a child environment without affecting the main environment objects, and just pass selected objects from the child environment back to the main environment:

```
myGlobal <- "initial value"  # create an object in the main environment
objectsOfMyDesire <- with(new.env(), {
  myGlobal <- paste(myGlobal, "CHANGED by the with()"); message(paste0("in with(): myGlobal = ", myGlobal, "\""))  # alter object inherited from main environment
  mySub <- paste("mySub:", toupper(myGlobal)); message(paste0("in with(), mySub = ", mySub))    # create object
  return(list("mySub" = mySub))  # Return the created objects that I want to keep
})  # run code within a child environment, and return certain values to the main environment.

# Result: in the main environment, myGlobal is unchanged, mySub does not exist, but objectsOfMyDesire$mySub has been created
myGlobal; objectsOfMyDesire$mySub
mySub
```

But when I source the very same code, everything that happens in the child environment impacts the main environment:

```
# Put code from within the "with()" above into a file, and then source() that file within a "with()":
rm(myGlobal, objectsOfMyDesire, mySub)
myTmpFile <- tempfile(pattern = "file", tmpdir = tempdir(), fileext = ".txt")
writeLines(con = myTmpFile, text = 'myGlobal <- paste(myGlobal, "CHANGED by the with()"); message(paste0("in with(): myGlobal = ", myGlobal));\n mySub <- paste("mySub:", toupper(myGlobal)); message(paste0("in with(), mySub = ", mySub))') 

# Having created a file to source(), run the example above, replacing some of the "with()" code with "source(myTmpFile)":
myGlobal <- "initial value"  # create an object in the main environment
objectsOfMyDesire <- with(new.env(), {
  source(myTmpFile)
  return(list("mySub" = mySub))  # Return the created objects that I want to keep
})  # run code within a child environment, and return certain values to the main environment.

# Result: in the main environment, myGlobal is CHANGED, mySub EXISTS, and objectsOfMyDesire$mySub has been created
myGlobal; objectsOfMyDesire$mySub
mySub

file.remove(myTmpFile)  # delete the temporary file
```

And even without `source()`, libraries created within `with()` persist:

```
# For this test, use some function from some package that you have installed, but not loaded in this session
exists("summarize")
with(new.env(), {
  message(paste("\n\nin with(), exists(\"summarize\")=", exists("summarize"),"\n\n"))
  library(dplyr)  # load the package that contains the function
  message(paste("\n\nin with(), exists(\"summarize\")=", exists("summarize"),"\n\n")) })
exists("summarize")  # The package that was loaded in the child environment persists into the main environment. This is not good. I do not want anything from the child environment to persist unless I explicitly specify it. 
#unloadNamespace("dplyr")
```

So, is there some way I can `source()` programs from a master program, without the sourced programs affecting the master program environment beyond just passing back what I explicitly specify?

Comment: Does `source(myTmpFile, local=TRUE)` do what you want? But to me this really seems like a misuse of the `source()` command. It's better used just to source R functions that you can call later. Treating scripts as if they were functions itself doesn't allow you to take advantage of normal R scoping rules. Or just make your own package for more reusable code.

Comment: I am also wondering ... why would you want to do this..? Is there really a good reason to do it this way?

Comment: @MrFlick - Thanks! local = TRUE solved the first half of my issue. Using that option, the objects created in the source'd code no longer get created in my main environment. 
Regarding functions and packages: The sourced code includes many programs written by many people for many different reasons - I do not want to require that everyone in our analysis group write their ad hoc programs as functions or packages.

Comment: @Steffen - I run a fairly large analytic group in a government agency. We have many analysts writing useful programs in R. Some programs produce objects (like graphs or tables) that we want to integrate into several dashboards, reports, emails, or the like, or they might create a data frame that has good, broader use. I am trying to create a method we can use to leverage each others' work without imposing a lot of restrictions on how that work gets done.

Answer (score 1):

I have found a partial solution:

```
# Call the program that creates some objects I want to use in the current program.
#   Run it in a new, child environment that I'll name calledProgram, so that it will not affect objects in the main environment.
source(file=programFileAndPath, local = calledProgram <- new.env(), echo=T)
# The called programs objects are now in the calledProgram object.
#   So I now add code to bring the objects I wanted from the called program into the main environment.
usefulDataFrame <- calledProgram$usefulDataFrame
niceGGPlot      <- calledProgram$niceGGPlot
rm(calledProgram)  # I have moved the objects that I need into the main environment, so I now delete the calledProgram object
```

That does not protect the search path or namespace of the session, so if the sourced code adds libraries, installs packages, or changes package versions, those changes would persist even after this code is run. But at least this keeps the called program from creating or altering objects in the environment of the main program.